# share photos on facebook through iOS create Album

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, facebook

When I post photo in faceboook one by one through ios. it creates a photo album,I want to post photo separately, don't create the album or thumbnails. upload single post at a time. I am doing R & D more than two days.

please provide a better solution.

Thanks,

```
UIImage *postImag = [UIImage ImageWithName:@"Hello.png"];
NSString *message = @"Hello Test Message";
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(postImag);
[params setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
    if (imageData ) {
        [params setObject:imageData forKey:@"source"];
    }

    /* make the API call */
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:params
    HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {
                                 if (error) {
                                     NSLog(@"Error: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
                                 } else {
                                     NSLog(@"Successfully shared.");
                                 }
                              completionAction();
                          }];
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. "please provide a better solution." A better solution than what? Please show us your code so we don't repeat what you have tried already.

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible. In the past you could specify the album id where you wanted this uploaded but this has been deprecated. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/photos